# Laravel get just updated rows in date range - using WhereBetween and Where in query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have jobs table in the database with the default columns *created_at* and *updated_at*.

I want to return the number of jobs created and the number updated.

However as the updated_at column is populated at the point of creation, I want to exclude any jobs where the updated_at value is the same as the created_at value (in order to get just the jobs that have been updated since being created).

I use the following code to get the number of updated jobs between a time range.

```
  $jobsUpdated = Job::where('id', $id)
            ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$value['fromDate'], $value['tillDate']])
            ->count();
```

How can I add another where clause to exclude those results which have the same value as created_at.

In theory something like:

```
            ->andWhere('updated_at', '!=' , 'created_at')
```

But andWhere does not exist, so this is just to show my thinking.

Thanks!

Comment: Just `where` works as `andWhere`, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
    $jobsUpdated = Job::where('id', $id)
           ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$value['fromDate'], $value['tillDate']])
           ->whereColumn('updated_at', '!=' , 'created_at')
           ->count();
```

to compare column value use `whereColumn()` function referenced by official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)